# Extension of the trivial bundle by the canonical bundle on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over a field $k$ and $K_X$ be its canonical line bundle. By the Serre duality, $\text{H}^1(X,K_X)$ is a one-dimensional $k$-vector space. On the other hand, $\text{H}^1(X,K_X)=\text{Ext}^1(O_X,K_X)$ so this vector space corresponds to the set of extensions of $O_X$ by $K_X$. Let $V$ be such an extension that corresponds to a nonzero vector in $\text{H}^1(X,K_X)$. This is a $2$-dimensional vector bundle on $X$.

**Question.** Is there exists a simple/concrete description of $V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is a smooth curve, the canonical bundle $\omega_X$ is nothing but the bundle of differentials $\Omega_X^1$, and the corresponding extension defines the **jet bundle**
$$
0 \to \Omega_X^1 \to J_X \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on why is that the jet bundle? For example, as defined here https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/jets.pdf

Comment: The extension class of the jet bundle (associated to a vector bundle) is the Atiyah class, and the trace of the Atiyah class is equal to the first Chern class of the corresponding vector bundle. So, if you take a line bundle with nonzero first Chern class, take its jet bundle, and twist back by the line bundle you started with, you get a nontrivial extension.

Comment: But that says that the trace of the extension class of $0 \to \Omega_X^1 \to J_X \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0$ is $c_1(\mathcal{O}_X)$, which is trivial. The approach of taking a line bundle with nonzero first chern class gives an extension $0 \to \Omega_X^1 \to JL \otimes L^{-1} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0$, but not with $J_X$ in the middle, right?

Comment: Sometimes the jet bundle of a vector bundle $E$ is defined as an extension of the form $0 \to \Omega^1_X \to J \to E^\vee \otimes E \to 0$, in the case of a line bundle it will be extension of $\mathcal{O}_X$ by $\Omega^1_X$ with the class equal to the Atiyah class of $E$. So, that's a question of convention.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $k=\mathbb C.$ Consider the uniformization of $X,$ which is given by an equivariant developing map of the universal covering of $X$ to the hyperbolic disc sitting inside the projective line $\mathbb CP^1$. Lift the corresponding $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$-representation to a $SL(2,\mathbb R)$-representation. Consider the corresponding flat $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$-bundle $(E,\nabla).$ The tautological line bundle  over $\mathbb CP^1$ corresponds to a well-defined holomorphic subbundle $L\subset E$ over $X.$ By its geometric construction, $L^2=K_X$, i.e. $L$ is a spin bundle. Then, $L\otimes E$ is independent of the choice of the monodromy lift, and is a non-trivial extension of $\mathcal O_X$ by $K_X$. $E$ is often called a Gunning bundle on $X$.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment. Let $g$ be the genus of $X$. One can see that the connecting map $H^0(X,O_X)\to H^1(X, K_X)$ is an isomorphism, and therefore that $h^0(V)= h^1(V)=g$. When $g=0$, Grothendieck's theorem implies that $V= O(a)\oplus O(b)$. The previous computation shows that $a,b<0$. Since  $\deg V= \deg K_X=-2$, we have $V= O(-1)\oplus O(-1)$.