# The indecomposable bundle on an elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

M. Atiyah (Theorem 5, p. 432 of ["Vector bundles on an elliptic curve"](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Enadler/atiyah.classification.pdf)) defines an indecomposable bundle of degree $0$ that has a global section for each rank $r$ (I'm thinking on an elliptic curve).

Is this the bundle of $r$-jets? Why is it not explained in the paper? Is the bundle of $r$-jets indecomposable on any curve of positive genus?

For me, the bundle of jets is the one defined by Vakil in ["A Beginner’s Guide to Jet Bundles from the Point of View of Algebraic Geometry"](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/files/jets.pdf)

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what paper you’re referring to, and gave a reference to where in the paper this bundle is defined.

Comment: Do you mean the bundle of $r$-jets of local biholomorphisms from the origin of the affine line, or $r$-jets of vector fields, or something else perhaps?

Comment: @JeremyRickard @ BenMcKay I have added references, I hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your main question for $r=1$, but for any smooth projective variety $X$. Interestingly, the answer is implicit in another paper of Atiyah's *Complex analytic connections in fibre bundles*, written the same year. (So perhaps this also answers your rhetorical question "Why is it not explained in the paper?".) Given a vector bundle $V$ on $X$, we have a canonical exact sequence
$$0\to \Omega_X^1\otimes V\to J^1(V)\to V\to 0$$
following the notation in Vakil's paper that you linked.
The extension class is now called the Atiyah class, and it gives the obstruction to finding an algebraic (or holomorphic, when the field is $\mathbb{C}$) connection on $V$. If $V=\mathcal{O}_X$, then it has such a connection, namely $d$.
Therefore the $1$-jet bundle  $J^1= J^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is decomposable.

Comment: Hmm I see, maybe I was being misguided by the first answer to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439917/extension-of-the-trivial-bundle-by-the-canonical-bundle-on-a-curve , where they say that the canonical nonzero element of $\mathrm{Ext}^1( \mathcal O_C, \Omega_C)$ is the jet bundle extension. Do you know know which extension $0 \to \Omega_C \to ?? \to \mathcal O_C \to 0$ could it be?

Comment: Yes, these answers contradict each other. I'll need to think further about it...